# Playing audio freezes the main thread

Tags: swift, multithreading

For some reason the following code freezes the main thread when I try playing audio. I've tried everything from dispatching to another thread but that doesn't do much. I even tried running the queue in async, but then I run into problems when the user clicks another audio file before the first one finishes loading. Any tips on which thread to use?

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queuename")
serialQueue.sync {

    if (jukeboxPlayer.jukebox != nil) {

        if let playingURL = jukeboxPlayer.jukebox?.currentItem?.URL {
            jukeboxPlayer.jukebox?.removeItems(withURL: playingURL)
        }

        jukeboxPlayer.jukebox?.append(item: JukeboxItem(URL: url), loadingAssets: true)

    } else {
        jukeboxPlayer.jukebox = Jukebox(delegate: self, items: [
            JukeboxItem(URL: url),
        ])
    }

    print("3.0")


    jukeboxPlayer.jukebox?.play()

    print("==========Started playing===========")

    self.showPlayer()
}
```

Also tried:

```
serialQueue.sync {
```

and

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
```

And here's the framework I use:

https://github.com/teodorpatras/Jukebox

Comment: did you try with `DispatchQueue.main.async` ?

Comment: that would just get the main thread. i want it to run on another thread so it doesn't freeze up the UI

Comment: I do think here: https://github.com/teodorpatras/Jukebox/blob/master/Example/Example/ViewController.swift you may find a very clear example of usage.